# Question about bayes framework relative to time

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics

I was wondering if there was a way to use Bayesian framework where you might favor more recent data over older data? Say you are doing work with 3pt shooting percentages where u might used historical data for the start of the new season as a prior but may want to add more "weight" to the newer data being introduced as the new season progresses.